# Tufte-style beamer presentations in Rmarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, tufte

I'd love to make "beamer presentations" [Tufte-style](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/tufte_handout_format.html) in Rmarkdown. There I can put in the YAML header either `output: beamer_presentation` or

```
output:
  tufte::tufte_html: default    
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

Is there any way to combine this? Or any other straightforward solution?

*Note:* I've asked the question [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397139/136969) on tex.stackexchange with no solution.

Comment: not sure how rmardown handles this, but in plain pandoc you'd simply define a custom template: http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

Comment: Given Tufte was famously against using PPT, perhaps this is by design ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several example of tufte style beamer presentation, e.g. https://github.com/ViniciusBRodrigues/simple-tufte-beamer

One can adjust them for rmarkdown like this:

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex

---

# {.plain}
\titlepage


# Titulo do slide

Este é um exemplo de texto.
```

with `preamble.tex`:

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[scaled=0.90]{helvet}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}


\title[Título da apresentação]{\textls[200]{\uppercase{Título da apresentação}}}
\author[Vinícius Barros Rodrigues]{\textls[200]{\uppercase{Vinícius Barros Rodrigues \\ \vspace*{0.2cm} Universidade Federal de Viçosa \\ \vspace*{0.7cm}}} \texttt{\lowercase{\textls[10]{viniciusbrbio@gmail.com}}}}

\date{}
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\fontfamily{phv}}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{author}{family=\fontfamily{phv}}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\itshape}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{0.7cm}\insertframetitle}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][left]
```

[image]

The complete rstudio project can be seen at https://rstudio.cloud/project/706957

Comment: Nice, I'm getting an error `pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xed': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream`, though. Could you make this more reproducible?

Comment: @jay.sf No idea about the pandoc error, it works fine in rstudio.cloud, I added a link to the complete project. You don't need the zip at all, it is for normal beamer and as written in my answer it needs to be adapted to rmarkdown.